# Recharts - Enable CSS transition for sectors on hover in PieChart with `isAnimationActive` as `true`

Tags: css-transitions, recharts

I'm trying to get some basic CSS transition for PieChart sectors on hover. It works as expected if the prop `isAnimationActive` is false, but I cannot get it to work combining both.
Inspecting the output in the browser I see no differences in the outputted mark-up.

Maybe this is more an Issue for Recharts than a question for SO.

You can try here, changing `isAnimationActive` prop from `false` to `true`:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pie-chart-with-hover-on-sector-gd9nkm

Comment: See https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/4216